# How to memorize 5500 English words within the shortest time?

Tags: vocabulary, pedagogy, memorization

I am considering to appear for [GRE](https://www.ets.org/gre/). For this purpose, I have bought a vocabulary book containing 5500 words.

It must be mentioned that I work 12 hours per day and thus I have limited free time.

My questions are:

- What major factors apply rapid study?
- Is learning by vocabulary an effective technique to prepare specifically for GRE test?

  - If so, how many days would be a realistic target?
  - If not, what are learning techniques which enable me well prepared within the shortest possible period of time?

Comment: That is over 90 words a day! A pretty tall order.

Comment: Also, not sure if this is on topic.

Comment: I see the comment about moving to ell stack exchange.  Is this an ELL (English language learner) issue?  GRE words are obscure even for people who know English.

Comment: To close-voters: pay attention that above comments about off-topic apply to Productivity.SE. IMHO, here it is a good question, but let me edit it a bit to make more constructive.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/3469/how-many-vocabulary-words-should-i-learn-every-day ?

Comment: Try this app to learn more words: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.fortylove.mywordlist.free

Answer (score 13):

**5500 words?!** Most GRE books only emphasize the most common 350 to 1500 words, 5500 seem to be slightly excessive. If you don't have at least 3 months to read that book (still about 60 a day), shift to some other that feature less but more selected GRE vocabularies.

**Focus on learning word roots.** Stay away from a long list of words in alphabetical order, instead, go for ones that display the meaning as well as the word roots (prefixes and suffixes) of the vocabularies. For example, *bene* is a prefix that means "good" and it forms words like *bene*/fit, *bene*/fiter, *bene*/ficial, *bene*/faction, *bene*/factor or *bene*/factress, *bene*/dict (blessed), *bene*/diction, *bene*/fice, and *bene*/volent, etc. That way, you can absorb many more words in one go.

**Use flash cards.** Thousands of words are hard to review, you can either buy the ready-to-use GRE flash cards, or make your own. Keep the pile with you and review whenever and wherever possible.

**Take a mock exam.** If you have not researched what taking GRE is like, I'd recommend trying a mock exam just to familiarize with the environment. You can check the GRE site to see if they have one available. Major tutoring companies may also be able to provide a few if you enroll in their prep courses. I have never gone to those commercial prep school, but if you're time-pressed having some professional help may not be a bad thing.

Comment: In response to: "Use flash cards.  Thousands of words are hard to review[...]"  Yes, it is difficult.  Programs like [Anki](http://ankisrs.net/) can help with managing large decks, though.

Comment: I agree; [repeat practice over time, and testing yourself](http://ideas.time.com/2013/01/09/highlighting-is-a-waste-of-time-the-best-and-worst-learning-techniques/) - whether with flashcards or practice tests - are the general learning techniques that have evidence showing they work.

Answer (score 3):

Rather than memorizing an arbitrary list of words, I strongly recommend that you learn each word individually. I’m a visual learner, so the way I learn is by associating words with pictures. For complicated words, I create short stories. Give it a try. It has worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

Play a small game with some of your friend or family members.

1. Make 3 piles of card where each card has 1-2 words on it with some points.
2. Now pull one card from each pile. And make a story over these words.

Whoever successfully makes a story will get points.

*Increase the number of cards from 3 to up to 7 later.

Answer (score 1):

Practice is the single thing teachers agree on to help you learn a language. Practice talking to native speakers, practice reading English books, and any time you come across a word you don't understand, look out up in a good dictionary.

It is impossible to predict how fast you will learn, as everyone is different.